# Getting Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response: Authorization required

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cross-browser

I'm trying to Run my selenium java code with `browserstack` but, when I try to run my script, it's showing an error. Can someone please help me to get this done?

This is selenium code:

```
 package priority;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

    public class browserstack {
        public static final String USERNAME = "fayaz9";
        public static final String AUTOMATE_KEY = "QBsbq4Ez4QUz6y3kYsoL";
        public static final String URL = "https://" + USERNAME + ":" + AUTOMATE_KEY + "@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub";

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
            caps.setCapability("browser", "Chrome");
            caps.setCapability("browser_version", "78.0");
            caps.setCapability("os", "Windows");
            caps.setCapability("os_version", "10");
            caps.setCapability("resolution", "1024x768");
            caps.setCapability("name", "Bstack-[Java] Sample Test");

            WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new java.net.URL(URL), caps);
            driver.get("http://www.google.com");
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

            element.sendKeys("BrowserStack");
            element.submit();

            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
            driver.quit();

        }
    }
```

And this is the error message, which I'm getting in my console:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response: Authorization required
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:115)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:75)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:139)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:582)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:136)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:149)
        at priority.browserstack.main(browserstack.java:24)
    Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Unable to determine type from: A. Last 1 characters read: A
    Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-4', revision: 'c2d955b49e'
    System info: host: 'FAYAZ', ip: '192.168.43.96', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_241'
    Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.peek(JsonInput.java:126)
        at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.lambda$buildCoercer$6(JsonTypeCoercer.java:140)
        at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.coerce(JsonTypeCoercer.java:126)
        at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:67)
        at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:53)
        at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:48)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:112)

    ... 7 more
```

Comment: I just ran the code as is and I didn't get any error

Comment: @WilfredClement - so any suggestion for me.. and one more thing is i will let you know that i'm getting some more messages in the console just above the error message

Comment: @WilfredClement
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[DEBUG] 2020-05-13 17:43:45.882 [main] InternalLoggerFactory - Using Log4J2 as the default logging framework
[DEBUG] 2020-05-13 17:43:45.988 [main] ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
[DEBUG] 2020-05-13 17:43:45.989 [main] ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.targetRecords: 4
[DEBUG] 2020-05-13 17:43:46.124 [main] Pl

Comment: @WilfredClement - please let me know the above mentioned message will be the root cause of my issue?